# How to get the value of href in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm sending the data from the controller to javascript through json and the json looks like this:

```
UsernameError: "&lt;p&gt;Username not valid, please&lt;/p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.google.com&quot;&gt; click here&lt;/a&gt; &lt;p&gt;to validate it.&lt;/p&gt;"
```

I'm transforming it in raw html, making it look like:

```
UsernameError: "<p>Username not valid, please</p><a href="www.google.com"> click here</a> <p>to validate it.</p>"
```

and when i'm trying to get what i have in `href` using this

```
 var href = $(decoded[0].innerText).attr('href');
```

is coming as `undefined`, but if i would only have the `a` tag in the json, the href value is set in the variable.

Any idea why i'm not able to get the href value if i have more tags in the json?

Comment: What **exactly** is `decoded`? Is it an array? How is it defined? Where do its values come from?

Comment: Whatever `decoded[0].innerText` is, you're using it as *selector* for jQuery. Are you sure that's what you want? Wait, are you asking how to extract `www.google.com` (an invalid href btw) from `UsernameError`?

Comment: You should use the id of the anchor tag as a selector for 1 element, or a classname for multiple, or the tagname for all.

Comment: If the _"json"_ looks like `UsernameError: ...`, then it ain't JSON

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/pyhaend1/ (again, `www.google.com` isn't a valid href, you need `https://www.google.com`)

Comment: @ChrisG you can use the `jQuery()` function to wrap arbitrary HTML however, it's not going to work the way (I think) OP wants it to

Comment: @Phil Right, I didn't think of that. My main issue though is that this is most likely an XY problem.

Comment: innerText? that is just text, not html

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to handle the content as it where real html-elements, you can create an virtual html-element with jquery and search for the a-tag with the find-method.

```js
let decodedString = '<p>Username not valid, please</p><a href="www.google.com"> click here</a> <p>to validate it.</p>';

let htmlContent = $('<div/>').html(decodedString);
let href = htmlContent.find('a').attr('href');

console.log(href);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
/href="([^\'\"]+)/g
```

Example at: http://regexr.com?333d1

**Update:** or easier via non greedy method:

```
/href="(.*?)"/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you try to use `.attr()` on multiple tags.

`.attr()` only works to grab an attribute on a single tag.

You have to only select the tag you want into your decoded.

Try :

```
var href = $(decoded[0].innerText).find('a').attr('href');
```